# Ruby Rails get records where a record doesn't already exist of a particular status

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a Item model (:name, :desc, ...) and a Price model (:item_id, :status, ...).
Item has many Prices & a Price belongs to an item.

I need to select all Items which have no Price or have no price with a :status of 'active'.
So if an Item has multiple prices but one is 'active' then I do not want to include it.

Thank you.

```
Item.includes(:prices).where(prices: {item_id: nil}).or(Item.includes(:prices).where.not(prices: {status: 'active'}))
```

Is the best I could come up with...

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few different ways to approach the problem - the simplest polyglot solution would be a subquery to fetch the "active prices":

```ruby
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :prices

  def self.without_active_prices
    subquery = Price.select(:item_id)
                    .where(status: 'active')
                    .where(
                      Price.arel_table[:item_id].eq(arel_table[:id])
                    )

    left_joins(:prices)
      .where(prices: { id: nil })
      .or(
        Item.where.not(id: subquery)
      )
  end
end
```

```sql
SELECT "items".* FROM "items" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "prices" ON "prices"."item_id" = "items"."id" 
WHERE (
  "prices"."id" IS NULL 
   OR "items"."id" NOT IN (
     SELECT "item_id" FROM "prices" WHERE "prices"."status" = $1 AND "prices"."item_id" = "items"."id"
   )
)
```

There are also more novel DB specific options such as a lateral join or using FILTER on Postgres:

```sql
Item.left_joins(:prices)
    .group(:id)
    .having(
      "COUNT(prices.*) = 0 OR COUNT(prices.*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'active') = 0"
    )
```

```sql
SELECT "items".* 
FROM "items" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "prices" 
ON "prices"."item_id" = "items"."id" 
GROUP BY "items"."id" 
HAVING (
  COUNT(prices.*) = 0 
  OR 
  COUNT(prices.*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'active') = 0
)
```

Comment: What you don't want to convert the second option to Arel? `Arel::Nodes::Or.new(Price.arel_table[Arel.star].count.eq(0),Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('FILTER',Price.arel_table[Arel.star].count,Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new([Arel::Nodes::UnaryOperation.new('WHERE',[Price.arel_table[:status].eq('active')])])).eq(0))`

Comment: @engineersmnky lazyness :)

Comment: haha @engineersmnky

Comment: @max thank you! I just woke up and had the idea of getting all the 'active' price id's in an array and filter them out; then getting then getting the records with a unique item_id.

I'm using postgres and this is the first time I have seen 'having' I will give that solution a whirl. 

Thank you everyone!

Comment: HAVING is like WHERE but it applies to the group instead of indivial rows - so its always used with GROUP.